# Derivation of a function's formulae from its graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, signal-processing

[image]

I am given the plot of a signal function. The expectation is to derive the full function given the graph's parameters.

Here's what I've come up with so far for the negative side of the function: $\Pi(\frac{t}{10})+3\Lambda(\frac{(t+2)}{3})$

where [image: definition of unit box function]

and [image: definition of unit triangle function]

Unfortunately I am lost as to how to deal with the plateau in the middle and subsequently the positive side. Any hints or tips please?

Comment: What are $\Pi$ and $\Lambda$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Apologies I did not clarify. They are the unit box and unit triangle function respectively.

Comment: And what are *those*?  Please do not assume that everyone here is familiar with the vocabulary and jargon that is used in your field.

Comment: @XanderHenderson $\Pi$ and $\Lambda$ are now classical notations in Signal Processing ; $\Pi(x)=\chi_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x)$ (characteristic function of this interval) and $\Lambda(x)=1-|x|$ on $[-1,1]$, and $\Lambda(x)=0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @JeanMarie I appreciate the explanation, but my goal was to emphasize that not everyone here is an expert in signal processing, but many folk here can answer the question (assuming that definitions are provided).

Comment: I can but agree.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Pardon my negligence. I added definitions for the two in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what is happening geometrically.  There are two or three features of the graph which seem important to capture:

1. There is a triangle on the right which appears to correspond to a scaled and translated copy of $\Lambda$.  Let
   $$ f(x) = 3 \Lambda\left(\frac{x-2}{3}\right). $$
   This function has the same graph as $\Lambda$, but translated to the right by $2$ units and scaled both horizontally and vertically by a factor of $3$.
2. There is a triangle on the left which appears to correspond to a scaled and translated copy of $\Lambda$.  Let
   $$ g(x) = 3 \Lambda\left(\frac{x+2}{3}\right). $$
   This function has the same graph as $\Lambda$, but translated to the right by $2$ units and scaled both horizontally and vertically by a factor of $3$.
3. It appears that both of these triangles have been translated up by one unit, but only on the interval $[-5,5]$.  This corresponds adding a horizontally scaled copy of $\Pi$ which has been left-translated by $5$ units.  Let
   $$ h(x) = \Pi\left( \frac{x+5}{10} \right). $$

Adding these three functions together seems to get the job done:
$$ f(x) + g(x) + h(x)
= 3\left( \Lambda\left( \frac{x-2}{3} \right)
+ \Lambda\left( \frac{x+2}{3} \right) \right)
+ \Pi\left( \frac{x+5}{10} \right). $$

[image]
(linky:  https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/czywnyrh )

Comment: Thank you. This was a perfect explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution adding even functions:

$$\Pi(t/10)+5 \Lambda(t/5) -4 \Lambda(t/2)+\Lambda(t)$$